# how to get all Emails addresses from an android device

Tags: android

How can I collect all the email address and not just the primary email? I have the below code that collect only 1 email address and send it as an event,

```
      **public String getEmails(){
          Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
          Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
          for (Account account : accounts){
              if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()){
                  return account.name;
              }
          } return"";

      }
```

abc.setUserEmails(this.getEmails(),this.getEmails());**

Comment: What does "collect all the email address" mean? There is no requirement for email clients to use `AccountManager`, let alone in a way that exposes email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean from the Android Contacts list, here is a fragment that should help:

Note:  I have misread the question, but Ill leave the code sample if someone is looking for  a way to get the email addresses from the contact manager.

```
public void getAddresses()
{
    try
    {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0)
        {

            while (cur.moveToNext())
            {
                count++;

                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                // Assuming you want this

                Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]
                        { id }, null);

                i=0;
                while (emailCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    // This would allow you get several email addresses
                    // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                    String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    String emailType = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                    System.out.println(email);  // please dont spam me

                    i++;
                }
                emailCur.close();


            }


        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```